# Equivalent Conditions on Equivalent Metrics

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Question from Royden's Real Analysis:

**Definition**:
Two metrics $\rho$ and $\sigma$ on a set $X$ are equivalent $\iff \exists $ constants $c_1,c_2>0$ such that $c_1\rho(x,y)\le \sigma(x,y)\le c_2\rho (x,y)\forall x,y\in X$ .

**Problem**:
Show that two metrics $\rho$ and $\sigma$ on a set $X$ are equivalent $\iff \exists $a constant $c>0$ such that $\frac{1}{c}\rho(x,y)\le \sigma(x,y)\le c\rho (x,y)\forall x,y\in X$ .

The proof of $\Leftarrow$ is quite trivial.

If we have two constants how can we come to a single constant ?

I am unable to show the converse part.Please help.

Comment: What's the problem? You've just copied and pasted the definition evidently.

Comment: In your problem, you have written there exists $c>0$ but in the remaining part, you have not mentioned what is the role of this $c$. You check the problem again. Because the problem is same as the definition. Probably it will be $\frac{1}{c}\rho (x,y)\le \sigma(x,y)\le c\rho(x,y).$

Comment: @AOrtiz;I have edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the converse, choose $c=\max({\large{\frac{1}{c_1}}},c2)$.

Then $1/c \le c_1\;$and$\;c_2 \le c$, hence
$$\frac{1}{c}\rho(x,y) \le c_1\rho(x,y)\le \sigma(x,y)\le c_2\rho (x,y)\le c\rho (x,y)$$
so this choice of $c\;$satisfies the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You want *both* $c_2 \le c$ and $\frac{1}{c} \le c_1$ and then you can use the $c_1,c_2$-version to go to the $c$-version. Note that:

$$\frac{1}{c} \le c_1 \text{ iff } 1 \le cc_1 \text{ iff } c \ge \frac{1}{c_1}$$

as $c_1, c_2 > 0$. So just define $c = \max(c_2, \frac{1}{c_1})$ and both are satisfied.